# Utilizar Fetch em JS para fazer chamada de um método do lado do servidor (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, fetch

Tenho uma pagina ASPX, chamada default.aspx e um default.aspx.cs sendo meu codigo no lado do servidor rodando no IIS 7, algo bem simples mesmo, escrito no VC Code. Alem das pastas JS, CSS e IMG (esses dois ultimos sem relevancia no problema em questão.).

No arquivo JS tenho uma função que faz uma requisição HTTP para o servidor e esse deveria executar um determinado metodo. (segue os codigos abaixo):

```
fetch('default.aspx/Enviar_Indicador_Novo',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({Data: data_Atualizacao, Pilar: pilar})
})
.then(response => console.log(response))
// .then(message => {console.log(message)})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

e:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Enviar_Indicador_Novo(string Data, string Pilar){
    ... metodo a ser executado e retornar uma string de "sucesso" ou "falha""
}
```

No inicio do meu arquivo ASPX, coloquei a tag: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Buscar_SQL.Index" %>`

`Busca_SQL` é meu namespace e o `Index` é minha partial class.

a resposta dessa requisição é essa: `Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxx/default.aspx/Enviar_Indicador_Novo', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

A questão é, ele não executa o método no lado do servidor, só informa a resposta com status 200, mesmo não executando o metodo.

Poderiam me ajudar? será que é alguma config no meu IIS? a unica coisa que eu fiz nele foi hospedar e configurar para rodar paginas ASPX.